# Images that don't exist anymore being displayed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, path

I have a function that changes some styling on click:

```
$('#button1').click(function() { 
        $('#button1').css("background-image","url(../img/menuicons/button1pr.gif)");
        $('#button2').css("background-image","url(../img/menuicons/button2un.gif)");
        return false;
    });
```

The strange thing is, when I click it it returns me images of old versions of the buttons that don't even exist on my local server anymore. What's going on here?

Comment: Try to clear your browser's cache

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are saved in your browser's cache most likely. Try clearing your browser's cache.

Comment: @Megh np. glad we could help.